# REST addViewField "Cannot handle the data at position 0."

Tags: javascript, rest, client-object-model

I'm currently writing an initialisation script for a SharePoint-hosted application which checks if a list (used for launcher items) exists. If it doesn't, then it runs through a series of processes to create the list, add fields and then update the view.

Here's a snippet of code which loops through the payload objects and creates a new field and adds said field to the view for each object. This script utilises AngularJS and ShareCoffee.

```
var payload = [{
    'Title': 'Icon URL',
    'FieldTypeKind': 11,
    'Required': true
},
{
    'Title': 'Destination URL',
    'FieldTypeKind': 11,
    'Required': true
}];

angular.forEach(payload, function (value, key) {
    $http(ShareCoffee.REST.build.create.for.angularJS({ url: 'web/lists/getByTitle(\'Launcher%20Items\')/Fields', payload: payload[key], hostWebUrl: hostweburl }))
    .success(function (data) {
        console.log('Created field with the title ' + payload[key].Title);
        // field created, add to view
        $http(ShareCoffee.REST.build.create.for.angularJS({ url: 'web/lists/getByTitle(\'Launcher%20Items\')/views/getByTitle(\'All%20Items\')/viewFields/addViewField(\'' + payload[key].Title + '\')', hostWebUrl: hostweburl }))
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log('Added element to view');
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        })
    })
    .error(function (data, status) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

This code should work fine, but when it runs I get an Error 400 response from SharePoint with the error code

> 1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException

As well as a message saying

> value: "Cannot handle the data at position 0."

Is there any reason why this would happen or what this means? Google doesn't seem to bring much back.

Answer (score 0):

The issues appears to be that rather than 'creating' a new record within the viewField, you instead 'update' the existing record.

Replacing the REST.build.create class with REST.build.update seems to resolve the issue.